# Why are GitHub files updated only using git commit

Tags: github, push, commit

I was reading on "git commit" and "git push", and it seems to be agreed that "commit" means "updating local repository" while "push" means "sending changes to remote repository". However, after I commit a file through Git Bash following the instructions from "https://www.invezzatechnologies.com/how-to-push-single-or-two-or-multiple-files-git-single-commit/", the changes are reflected on my GitHub repository. I am confused because I thought I need to do "git push". Thanks!

Comment: What commands did you execute exactly?

Comment: @tkausl, for commit, I used "git commit -m "Test" test.ipynb". The file is in C:\User\Doc\GitHub. Prior to this command, I did steps 1-8 (https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/managing-files-in-a-repository/adding-a-file-to-a-repository-using-the-command-line). Step 9 seems to push all the files but I want to do one file, so I found the instructions in the "invezzatechnologies" website in the original question.

Comment: You are correct, `git commit` will not push. You pushed after you committed, check your scrollback or `history`. The Invezzatechnologies guide is confusing push with commit, based on that I would avoid their advice. Perhaps the confusion is that `git push` pushes all your commits.

Comment: @Schwern, sounds good. Yeah, I am new to this and tried a lot of things - the history is not as clean as I would have hoped it to be. Your last sentence sounded that git push does push all the commits. Would you advise the syntax to only push select files? Also, does one need to commit the file first before push, or just push it?

Comment: @tkausl, my apologies. I meant steps 1-8 in this doc (https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/importing-your-projects-to-github/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line)

Comment: @ZoeH You can't do it with `git push` alone. `git push` only sends whole commits and *all* their parent commits. Instead, restructure your branch locally first so it only contains what you want on top of the origin branch, then push that. How you do that depends on what you're trying to do. Start with [Pro Git's chapter on Branches](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell) then read [Rewriting History](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History). If you're still stuck, ask another question.